# c# Expression<Func<type1, type2>> возникает ошибка

Tags: c#, lambda

Есть такое выражение:

```
return Restrictions.Where<EntityType>((_receptionCompaignSourceFilter & x.Available) > 0);
```

Которое вызывает ошибку времени исполнения:

> Системная ошибка: На переменную "x" типа "XYZ.EntityType" имеется ссылка из области "", но она не определена

При этом такой код рабочий:

```
return Restrictions.Where<EntityType>(_receptionCompaignSourceFilter > x.Available);
```

Но такой код меня слабо интересует, мне нужно проверить именно битовые флаги.
Не могу понять, что не так.

Comment: нужно больше кода. Что за `x`? Откуда берется? когда заполняется?

Answer (score 1):

x в скобках не определена. Может все таки так

```
return Restrictions.Where<EntityType>(x => (_receptionCompaignSourceFilter & x.Available) > 0);
```